# Unable to pass variables to run docker container

Tags: bash, shell, variables, docker, environment-variables

I am trying to pass some variables to run my docker container. I have this in my dockerfile

```
#base stuff here
CMD ["echo", "$ENV"]
```

The output I get is this

```
$ENV
```

I am running my container like this

```
docker run -e ENV='hello' imagename
```

Why is it printing out $ENV and not my variable? If I start an interactive bash session then it will print out my variable but it through this way.

Comment: Add your Dockerfile to your question.

Comment: The first highlighted code is my docker file